# How to achieve expanded abbreviations on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys, productivity

On Windows, AutoHotKey enables you to write short scripts to recognize keystrokes and then expand them if they match a shortened abbreviation.

For example, if I type `4111` and hit `space` I can expand that to `4111111111111111` to be an expanded credit card. I can also do things like `addr` and hit `space` and it can type your entire address.

How can I do this on Mac OS X?

I've heard that Automation, built-in on Mac, can be useful but I did not find this expanding abbreviations for keystrokes when I searched the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

btw, QuicKeys will run forever in trial mode, if you really want it - though it hasn't been updated in forever & is a bit flaky these days. I stopped using it around Mountain Lion.

.. but the best method would be System Prefs > Keyboard > Text

Type whatever shortcut you want in the left side, & any replacement text on the right - you can include any kind of text, unicode, punctuation, emoji, etc etc
though if you need carriage returns you need to copy/paste the text from somewhere else, e.g. TextEdit as you cannot directly enter a carriage return.

I use it for everything from making 'keys' in SE…  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  etc to my email, phone, full postal address [with carriage returns] & even my common typos that autocorrect won't fix

[image]

Comment: This seems to work great. However it doesn't work within a browser window. It seems to only work within Mac applications such as notepad/finder. Do you know of any way to expand it's functionality to a browser window?

Comment: the browser needs to be 'mac text' compliant. Safari certainly is, I use it all the time for things like those Cmd key combis for stack exchange etc. The only app I know of that they don't work in is any Second Life (virtual world) 'viewer' as they really don't follow the Mac HUI guidelines, anywhere else they work for me.

Comment: Ok great thanks, definitely works in Safari. Hope I'll find something that works in Chrome, but this is good info to know anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a great solution for text expanding in Chrome (Any OS). It's using: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-text-expander-for-go/iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp

Tetsujin's answer works very well in Safari, but my main need was in Chrome (running on Mac OSX).